# Error in json view invalid json ouput

Tags: php, json

It says invalid json

{"userDetails": "RefId": 565521, {"key":[{"SNO":"565566","Type":"0","Desc":"0"},{"SNO":"12","Type":"1","Desc":"0"}]}, "success":true}

I want to add RefId while including it says invalid json please see and let me know whr m i wrong

Comment: *It says invalid json* yep, agree with you. Now what is the question? (This will tell you what's wrong: http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: I want to add RefID but adding it its going invalid pls suggest me

Comment: Use http://www.jslint.com/ to check your Json

Comment: please update my json format and put in right way

Answer (score 0):

Your json should be like that :

```
{"userDetails": {"RefId": 565521, "key":[{"SNO":"565566","Type":"0","Desc":"0"},{"SNO":"12","Type":"1","Desc":"0"}]}, "success":true}
```

And you should generate it like that :

```
$resultJson = array(
    'userDetails' => array(
        'refId' => $reference_id,
        'key' => $arr
    ),
    'success' => true
);

echo json_encode($resultJson);
```

Comment: echo '{"userDetails": {"RefId": '.json_encode($reference_id).', '.json_encode($array).', "success":true}';

where is error in my code

Comment: And the content of your $array ? can you dump it in your post ?

Comment: while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery)){
   
   $arr[] = $result;
   $array = array("key"=>$arr);
 }
 
  echo '{"userDetails": {"RefId": '.$reference_id.', '.json_encode($array).', "success":true}';

Answer (score 0):

You have not written it correctly:

```
{
"userDetails": [{
    "RefId": 565521, 
    "key": [{"SNO":"565566","Type":"0","Desc":"0"},{"SNO":"12","Type":"1","Desc":"0"}], 
    "success" : true
}] 
}
```